# adverbials part II... I left the building with him...

Tags: ambiguity, clauses, prepositions

Can one say

a. I left the kitchen with the water running.

b. I went to his house with my brother in jail.

c. I went out of the bedroom with her naked.

d. I left the building with my brother injured.
?

In a-c we have two facts. 
a1) I left the kitchen. The water was running.

b1) I went to his house. My brother was in jail when I did.

c1) I went out the bedroom. She was naked when I did.

'd' becomes kind of ambiguous though, doesn't it?

d1) I left the building. When I left the building my brother was injured.

d2) I left the building with my brother, who was injured.

Would you agree with that?

Many thanks.

Comment: Doubtless there are contexts where these might sound less weird, but an adverbial (or adjectival) using 'with' should not be semantically over-disparate from the main clause (I left the kitchen with a glass of wine / I left the kitchen with my sister / I left the kitchen with the open range / I left the kitchen with my nerves intact / ??I left the kitchen with my brother in jail).

Comment: What I understand from the first four sentences and the latter four sentences are completely different.

Comment: This is the kind of ambiguity that so many journalist headings are based on: "while" and "as"  are also perfect to connect two potentially unrelated things and cast shadows on either.